# What does type aliasing through reference (of `signed` to `unsigned`) with `reinterpret_cast` do?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, integer-overflow, reinterpret-cast

My questions are:

1. As of which version of the standard does the following code become valid (if any)?
2. What is the observable behavior of the program? (In C++20)

```cpp
#include <climits>

int main() {
  int foo = INT_MAX;
  ++reinterpret_cast<unsigned&> (foo); // foo = static_cast<int> (foo + 1u)
  return INT_MIN == foo;
}
```

Based on the following excerpt I believe this program returns 1. (See: [Example on Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/8Gjz35Ke7)).

> [7.6.1.10 Reinterpret cast [expr.reinterpret.cast]](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.reinterpret.cast)
>
> > [1](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.reinterpret.cast#1)
> > The result of the expression `reinterpret_­cast<T>(v)`  is the result of converting
> > the expression `v` to type `T`.  If `T` is an lvalue reference type […] the result is an lvalue;
>
> > [7](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.reinterpret.cast#7)
> > An object pointer can be explicitly converted to an object pointer of a different type.
> > When a prvalue `v` of object pointer type is converted to the object pointer type “pointer to cv T”, the result is `static_­cast<cv T*>(static_­cast<cv void*>(v))`.
> > *[[Note 6](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.reinterpret.cast#note-6): Converting a pointer of type “pointer to T1” that points to an object of type T1 to the type “pointer to T2” (where T2 is an object type and the alignment requirements of T2 are no stricter than those of T1) and back to its original type yields the original pointer value.
> > — end note]*
>
> > [11](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.reinterpret.cast#11)
> > A glvalue of type T1, designating an object x, can be cast to the type “reference to T2” if an expression of type “pointer to T1” can be explicitly converted to the type “pointer to T2” using a reinterpret_­cast.
> > The result is that of `*reinterpret_­cast<T2 *>(p)` where p is a pointer to x of type “pointer to T1”.
> > No temporary is created, no copy is made, and no constructors ([[class.ctor]](https://eel.is/c++draft/class.ctor) or conversion functions ([[class.conv]](https://eel.is/c++draft/class.conv)) are called.

---

Further reading:
TL;DR: The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74102375/9282847).

> 6.8.2.6  [[basic.fundamental]](http://www.eel.is/c++draft/basic.fundamental)
> [6](http://www.eel.is/c++draft/basic.fundamental#6) A fundamental type specified to have a **signed or unsigned integer type** as its underlying type has the **same object representation, value representation, alignment requirements** ([[basic.align]](http://www.eel.is/c++draft/basic.align)), and range of representable values as the underlying type.
> Further, each value has the same representation in both types.

> 6.8.1.4 [[basic.types.general]](http://www.eel.is/c++draft/basic.types.general)
> [4](http://www.eel.is/c++draft/basic.types.general#4) The object representation of an object of type T is the sequence of N unsigned char objects taken up by the object of type T, where N equals sizeof(T).
> The value representation of an object of type T is the set of bits that participate in representing a value of type T.
> Bits in the object representation that are not part of the value representation are padding bits.
> For trivially copyable types, the value representation is a set of bits in the object representation that determines a value, which is one discrete element of an implementation-defined set of values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has been permitted for all versions prior to C++20 according to the strict aliasing rule:

> If a program attempts to access the stored value of an object through an lvalue of other than one of the following types the behavior is undefined:
>
> ...
>
> - a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to the dynamic type of the object,

C++20 changed the form of the strict aliasing rule, but [the signed/unsigned variation remains permissible](http://www.eel.is/c++draft/expr.prop#basic.lval-11):

> If a program attempts to access the stored value of an object through a glvalue whose type is not similar to one of the following types the behavior is undefined:
>
> ...
>
> - a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to the dynamic type of the object

Here the dynamic type is `signed int`, your glvalue has the corresponding unsigned type `unsigned int`, so the access is allowed.

C++20 also made the result well-defined by mandating two's-complement encoding of signed numbers.  Previously you would manipulate the bit representation in a well-defined way but there was no particular guarantee on what value came out when read as `signed int` later.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. As of which version of the standard does the following code become valid (if any)?

Prolly none.

> 2. What is the observable behavior of the program? (In C++20)

The behavior is undefined: `++reinterpret_cast<unsigned&> (foo);` stores the INT_MAX + 1 value into `foo`. Now, if you read [[basic.fundamental]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/basic.fundamental#1.sentence-5):

> The range of representable values for a signed integer type is −2^{N−1} to 2^{N−1}−1 (inclusive), where N is called the *width* of the type.

as applying to [[expr.ass]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/expr.ass#2), then storing 2^{N-1}, which is not representable, is prolly UB.

But OK, the above reasoning may look uncertain, we assume the behavior is defined and we've stored INT_MAX + 1 into an `int` object. Then, in `return INT_MIN == foo;`, the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion is applied to `foo`, which means that

> [(3.4)](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/conv.lval#3.4) — the object indicated by the glvalue is read ([[defns.access]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/defns.access)), and the value contained in the object is the prvalue result.

So the result should be an `int` prvalue with the INT_MAX + 1 value. Now, [[expr.pre]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/defns.access)

> If during the evaluation of an expression, the result is not mathematically defined or not in the range of representable values for its type, the behavior is undefined.

kicks in and explicitly says that producing a value outside representable range is UB.

Comment: It stores the value into `foo` **using the type `unsigned int`**.  The expression is valid in unsigned arithmetic; the resulting value will be within the range of `unsigned int` and stored into the storage of `foo`, which is permitted by the strict aliasing rule.  Beginning with C++20, reading `foo` as its own type (`signed int`) is defined to use two's complement representation and so the final value is determined. In previous versions that interpretation step was platform specific and could potentially result in a trap (just like overwriting a `signed int`'s representation through std::byte)

Comment: From another perspective, your reasoning reaches two dramatically different conclusions depending on whether the `unsigned` lvalue reference is used to store `reinterpret_cast<const unsigned&>(INT_MIN)` or `INT_MAX + 1u`... but on a two's complement platform, both of these are the same value.  And the first one is known to round-trip....

Comment: @BenVoigt _It stores the value into foo using the type unsigned int. The expression is valid in unsigned arithmetic; the resulting value will be within the range of unsigned int and stored into the storage of foo, which is permitted by the strict aliasing rule._ This is what my answer says, no? Per https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/expr.ass#2, the result of the right operand is stored, which is INT_MAX+1 (2^31, if width is 32).

Comment: @BenVoigt _reading `foo` as its own type (signed int) is defined to use two's complement representation_ Per https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/intro.races#13.sentence-2 the value is 2^31, because this is what is stored by the visible (here one can say "the last", since no multiple threads are involved) side effect

Comment: Possibly it's a Standard defect, but that clause on race conditions is *clearly* not intended to handle type-punning; applying it pedantically breaks not only this case but also https://eel.is/c++draft/basic#types.general-3  The only sensible interpretation of "value stored by the last side effect" is the one that takes https://eel.is/c++draft/basic#types.general-4 into consideration and uses the object representation stored by the last side effect to create a value representation respecting the type used in `return INT_MIN == foo` which is `signed int`.

Comment: @BenVoigt _Possibly it's a Standard defect_ When I proposed to fix this, I didn't get unanimous support. I was told that there is `bit_cast` if one wants bits reinterpretation. So no need to make reading/writing through corresponding (un)signed lvalue doing any bits reinterpretation/modulo shifting the value, if it is outside the range. And I don't get how https://eel.is/c++draft/basic#types.general-3 is broken.

Comment: There's no way to make inspection of an object's representation bytes work, if "The value shall be the value stored by the last visible side effect." means the value in the side effect's type.  `double d = 4.2; char buf[sizeof d]; memcpy(buf, &d, sizeof d);` does not try to store `4.2` eight times.

Comment: `bit_cast` is needed for reinterpretations which are not directly allowed by the strict aliasing rule.  The reinterpretations in question here, bidirectionally between `signed int` and `unsigned int`, and also for reading the representation bytes using `char` / `unsigned char` / `std::byte`, are directly allowed and do not need `bit_cast`.

Comment: _There's no way to make inspection of an object's representation bytes work_ As you likely known, accessing object representation is a huge separate topic. It is not even clear if storing (which is a side-effect) into an object counts as a side-effect on the bytes in its object/value representation. Luckily, this question doesn't touch this (accessing object representation) topic.

Comment: "Accessing object representation" means the same as "Type punning within the restrictions of the strict aliasing rule".  They are the same topic, and it is applicable to this question.

Comment: @BenVoigt Please file an issue or write a paper to promote your view of how C++ object model should look like. I've answered how it works now.

Comment: I [already mentioned what I think](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74102221/what-does-type-aliasing-through-reference-of-signed-to-unsigned-with-rein/74103788#comment130886045_74103788), but because I edited a comment you might have missed it:  "The only sensible interpretation of "value stored by the last side effect" is the one that takes eel.is/c++draft/basic#types.general-4 into consideration and uses the object representation stored by the last side effect to create a value representation respecting the type used to read the value, which in `return INT_MIN == foo` is `signed int`. "

Comment: @BenVoigt I think _For trivially copyable types, the value representation is a set of bits in the object representation that determines a value_ is defective. E.g. for `int a[2][2]`, both `&a[0][2]` and `&a[1][0]` (when stored into an object) usually have the same value representation, but these are different values, and pointers are trivially-copyable. So the value representation does not determine the value for trivially-copyable types.

Comment: But they *are* the same value, you wouldn't claim that `p1 != p2`.  C++ used to have a concept of "safely-derived pointer value" which was removed and I'm not sure what it was replaced with.  Note that for `int a[2][2];` both those pointers are valid / safely-derived, because pointer arithmetic is allowed throughout a complete object.... but I stipulate that other examples exist for which the same pointer value may be valid or invalid depending on its derivation.

Comment: @BenVoigt _But they are the same value, you wouldn't claim that `p1 != p2`_ When `p1` and `p2` have (are) the same value, then `p1 == p2` is true; the inverse is not true. _C++ used to have a concept of "safely-derived pointer value"_ This is not relevant, it was added for garbage collection support, which turned out to be useless. What is relevant is the pointer values taxonomy added in C++17 and which is still alive: https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/basic.compound#3.sentence-8